# Python Printing and multiplying strings in Print statement

Tags: python, string, printing, while-loop

I am trying to write a simple python program that prints two ##, then # #, and increases the number of spaces in between the #'s each time. Here is the code I tried:

```
i=0

while (i<=5):
 print ("#" (" " * i) "#")
 #print (" " * i)
 #print ("#" "#")
```

The multiplication works in the first line of code I tested then commended out, I see it in the shell each time it prints one more space.

Printing two #'s works also.

I can't figure out how to combine it into one statement that works, or any other method of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=0     
while (i<=5):
    print( "#" +(" "*i)+ "#")
    i=i+1
```

You need to add the strings inside the print statement and increment i.

Comment: Thank you, that works great, I didn't know using + inside a print statement works in Python, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also do `print( "#",(" "*i),"#")`

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah Don't you have two extra spaces using `print('#\," "*i,'#')`?

Comment: Oh yeah, it adds an extra space as the separator, this works though: `print( "#",(" "*i),"#", sep='')`

Answer (score 2):

You want to print a `string` that depends an a variable. There are other methods to build a `string` but the simplest, most obvious one is *adding* together some fixed pieces and some computed pieces, in your case a `"#"`, a sequence of spaces and another `"#"`. To add together the pieces you have to use the `+` operator, like in `"#"+"   "+"#"`.

Another problem in your code is the `while` loop, if you don't increment the variable `i` its value will be always `0` and the loop will be executed forever!

Eventually you will learn that the idiom to iterate over a sequence of integers, from `0` to `n-1` is `for i in range(n): ...`, but for now the `while` loop is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
  i=0
  while (i<=5):
     print ('#' + i * ' ' + '#')
     i = i + 1
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, the OP uses Python 3, could you please edit your answer to reflect the different `print` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def test(self, number: int):
   for i in range (number)):
      print('#' +i * ''+ '#')
      i+=1
return
```